# How to parse a boolean expression in Haskell?

Tags: parsing, haskell, functional-programming, programming-languages, evaluation

I have a file called `Parser.hs` and have defined methods for evaluating a boolean expression. In that file, I have the following:

```
-- implementing parsing bool operations, these are 'and' and 'or'
parseBoolOp :: Parser BoolOp
parseBoolOp =
  do symbol "and" >> return And
    <|> do symbol "or" >> return Or

-- a bool expression is the operator followed by one or more expressions that we have to parse
-- TODO: add bool expressions
boolExpr :: Parser Expr
boolExpr = BoolExpr <$> parseBoolOp <*> (pure <$> parseExpr)

-- the main parsing function which alternates between all the options you have
parseExpr :: Parser Expr
parseExpr =
  do
    parseAtom
    <|> parseParens notExpr
    <|> parseParens boolExpr
    <|> parseParens parseExpr
```

In another file called `Eval.hs`, I have defined the following methods. I am trying to evaluate a bool expr using calcBoolList and evalListOfExprs:

```
-- call them whenever I want to generate an error
evalError :: ErrorT -> Evaluator a
evalError err = E (\_ -> Left err)

-- this evaluates a list of expressions and returns a list of values
-- by mapping an evaluator function (using <$>) over the list of expressions
evalListOfExprs :: ValueEnv -> [Expr] -> [Either ErrorT Value]
evalListOfExprs env exprs =
  ( \expr ->
      case eval evalExpr (env, expr) of
        Right (res, _) -> Right res
        Left msg -> Left msg
  )
    <$> exprs

-- evaluates a bool expression, this first evaluates all the
-- arguments to the bool expression and then uses calcBoolList
-- to calculate the boolean operation over the arguments. Note that
-- first, I use evalListOfExprs to evaluate the arguments. Then
-- I used calcBoolList with the right op on it
evalBoolExpr :: Evaluator Value
evalBoolExpr = do
  (env, BoolExpr op exprs) <- next
  -- TODO: implement the rest!
  case calcBoolList op (evalListOfExprs env exprs) of
    Right v1 -> return v1
    Left err -> evalError err

-- determine which bool operation to use to fold with by the kind of BoolOp passed in
calcBoolList :: BoolOp -> [Either ErrorT Value] -> Either ErrorT Value
calcBoolList op lst = case op of
  And -> boolOpFold (&&) lst
  Or -> boolOpFold (||) lst

-- parses the string then evaluates it
parseAndEval :: String -> Either ErrorT (Value, (ValueEnv, Expr))
parseAndEval str = do
  (ast, _) <- parse parseExpr str
  -- here, [] represents the empty environment
  eval evalExpr ([], ast)

-- parseAndEvalEnv = parseAndEvalEnv [] -- could replace the code above with this <-- because we defined parseAndEvalEnv below

-- parseAndEvalEnv :: ValueEnv -> String -> Either ErrorT (Value, (ValueEnv, Expr))
-- parseAndEvalEnv env str = do
--   (ast, _) <- parse parseExpr str
--   -- here, [] represents the empty environment
--   eval evalExpr ([], ast)

-- extract the value from the result, which contains extra stuff we don't need to see
getValue :: Either ErrorT (Value, (ValueEnv, Expr)) -> Either ErrorT Value
getValue (Right (val, _)) = Right val
getValue (Left err) = Left err

-- takes a string and parses it, then it tries to evaluate it
evalStr :: String -> Either ErrorT Value
evalStr = getValue . parseAndEval
```

The expressions types and value types are contained in this file called `Expr.hs`:

```
-- define the operator types
data BoolOp = And | Or deriving (Show, Eq)

-- define the expression types
data Expr
  = BoolExpr BoolOp [Expr]
  deriving (Show, Eq)

-- define the type for values, which in our mini language
-- can be integers, bools, pairs, or closures
data Value
  = BoolVal Bool
  deriving (Show, Eq)
```

When I run `evalStr "(and true (and false true) true)"`, which should return `Right (BoolVal False)`, it instead returns `Left (ParseError "'a' didn't match expected character")`. Is my evaluator wrong or is it the `boolExpr` in my Parser file?

Answer (score 1):

Your `boolExpr` doesn't address `and x y`. You write

```
boolExpr = BoolExpr <$> parseBoolOp <*> (pure <$> parseExpr)
```

which means to parse an operator, and then parse exactly one expression, and wrap that expression in a singleton list (here `pure :: a -> [a]`). You probably want something like

```
boolExpr = BoolExpr <$> parseBoolOp <*> parseExpr `sepBy1` spaces
```

to allow multiple subexpressions.

Comment: What is ```sepBy1``` spaces in this case?

Comment: I've never learned ```sepBy1 spaces```. Is there an alternate way?

Comment: It depends what parser library you're using. `sepBy1` is in most of them as far as I know, but you can implement it yourself if it's not in yours.